# SQL JOIN --- non-cartesian inner join

Tags: sql, join

I have the following query:

```
--UPDATE
UPDATE p.fact_usersortcustomer
set
  cellid   = usc.cellid,
  dwupdatedate = getdate()
from s.userSortCustomer usc
JOIN t.append_fact_usersortcustomer  ON usc.actiondate = t.actiondate AND usc.ucdmid = t.ucdmid AND usc.sortid = t.sortid
```

But the update doesn't work because I am getting the following error:

> [Error] Script lines: 10-17 ------------------------
>    ERROR: Target table must be involved in a non-cartesian inner join

Any ideas?

Comment: What database? Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc?

Comment: Are you trying to update a table that's not used either in the from nor the join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table after your `update` is not mentioned in the `from`.  This causes the "cartesian product".  Presumably, you want something like this:

```
UPDATE p
    set cellid= usc.cellid,
        dwupdatedate = getdate()
     from s.userSortCustomer usc join
          t.append_fact_usersortcustomer t
          ON usc.actiondate = t.actiondate AND usc.ucdmid = t.ucdmid AND usc.sortid = t.sortid join
          p.fact_usersortcustomer p
          ON . . . ;
```

However, I do not know what the `join`conditions are.  They go where the `. . .` is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use

```
UPDATE p.fact_usersortcustomer usc
set
  cellid = usc.cellid,
  dwupdatedate = getdate()
FROM (select ucdmid, sortid, actiondate from append_fact_usersortcustomer) a    
WHERE usc.ucdmid = a.ucdmid
  AND usc.sortid = a.sortid
  AND usc.actiondate = a.actiondate;
```